# E_DEPRECATED errors are enabled in your PHP configuration

Tags: php, joomla, moodle

i am using Moodle and joomla , and i use joomdle , but i face this message

> E_DEPRECATED errors are enabled in your PHP configuration

this message describe in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAZJw.png)

my error reporting in php.ini is :

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT

how i can solve this problem ?

#### Edit

Image moved from answer section:

this is image of joomdle
[image: error reporting]

---

this is image of joomdle
[image: error reporting]

Comment: i attach image of error in below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your php.ini to have this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: no i change this line instead my correspond line in php.ini but i face with same page and same error

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Did you try changing your php.ini to have the line I suggested and it still gives your error after restart?

Comment: Joomla's configuration allows one to set a custom error reporting level, which overrides the one set in php.ini .